# in eclipse: NullPointerException at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.addons.dndaddon.DragAgent.dragFinished(DragAgent.java:171)

Tags: eclipse

While drag and drop file tab to reorder open files of different perspective we are getting NullPointer error in DND code

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.addons.dndaddon.DragAgent.dragFinished(DragAgent.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.addons.dndaddon.PartDragAgent.dragFinished(PartDragAgent.java:93)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.addons.dndaddon.DnDManager.finishDrag(DnDManager.java:276)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.addons.dndaddon.DnDManager.startDrag(DnDManager.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.addons.dndaddon.DnDManager$1.dragDetected(DnDManager.java:87)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:127)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4362)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1113)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4180)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3769)

Comment: Please show the code, we can't debug it without code.

Comment: I take it you are the person who reported this as bug [515879](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=515879). Since this is an error in Eclipse code I don't think you are going to get an answer here.

Answer (score 0):

We have two different types of editors, each editor has its own perspective, when these two files are open in editor and we drag the file tab in editor to swap the order of files we  are getting this error. its not feasible to share the source code as its big code and not getting what  code exactly need to attach.